# Where does evil come from in Yazidism?

Tags: evil

In the Yazidi religion there is an angel called Melek Taus, the "Peacock Angel," who in other faiths, such as Islam and Christianity, is understood as the equivalent of the fallen angel who became the Devil, known by various other names in either example, and thought in some interpretations to be the source of evil in the world.

In Yazidism, however, Melek Taus is known as a good angel and an agent of God. With that being the case, what is the origin and ontology of evil in Yazidism?

Comment: Hi, Max. I added some details to try to explain what you're asking, by way of expanding on basic background info about Yazidism that might not be readily known to others (in order to keep the Question Open). Feel free to make your own Edit(s) if my input deviates from your intention.

Comment: @Adinkra, generally i dislike when people are editing other peoples' questions. I asked it precisely as i asked it - and it was correct. You rewrote question "Wherre...", please correct it to "where"...

Comment: Are you able to roll back the changes yourself?

Comment: @Max : Apologies for the spelling error. It's been fixed now. Apart from that, I was trying to elaborate on what I thought the intent of your question was, since there's was a Vote to Close it on account of the detail it was lacking. Of course I might have misinterpreted your intent so, like I said in my 1st Comment, if there's anything about my Edit that you don't want or like, you absolutely could change it or, as cmw says, just Roll Back (essentially _undo_ ) the changes that anyone makes to your work on here, no problem.

Comment: @Adinkra, no probs, thanks. let's wait for knowledgeable colleagues to give any hints on the topic itself ;)